# React proxy communication with Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-fullstack

I tried to build app with React + Node and it works just fine. It uses "proxy": "http://localhost:3001" in package.json file. But what I really like to avoid is to use "http://localhost:3001" inside package.json. I'd like to move this to config file but obviously I cannot import it to package.json file then. So my question is: is there a place this proxy is rendered and where I can import config setting.

Has anyone of you has problem like that?

Answer (score -1):

Well next time please specify that you are creating app with `create-react-app` nobody is here to guess your enviroment. In this case you have only 1 option, eject, `yarn eject` this will eject your create-react-app and then you can find `scripts/start.js` https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js#L83 where you can set this value to whatever, you can for example replace it with `process.env.PROXY` and then run your app with `PROXY=<proxy_url> yarn start` and have this variable dynamic